# British and American slang words for immigrants?

Tags: slang, phrase-requests, humor, single-word-requests

What slang words or phrases do British/American English speakers use for (poor) immigrants?

Comment: In US English the terms have traditionally been specific to individual national/ethnic groups -- spic, mick, wop, chink, gook, etc.  Granted, the terms were often carried over to people who were neither poor nor immigrants, but this is the nature of such prejudices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ones I could think up of was [offensive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wog), so I wouldn't list it.

> **Greenhorn**
>   **Alien**
>   **Floater**

There is also "Pomegranate", which is rhyming slang with "Immigrant". This term is shortened to "pommy" and used by Australians to refer to Britons.

"Wetback" is a derogatory term for Mexican illegal "immigrants", not humorous and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Do you have any kind of reference for the Immigrant -> Pomegranate -> pommy/pom etymology? I always thought pom was a reference to potatoes.

Comment: Nevermind, I did my own research: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pommy You are quite correct.

Comment: It's heard quite commonly around here.

Comment: Britishers is used commonly? Or Pommy?

Comment: @Matt Ellen, Pommy is used frequently. There is a cricket club which I play for, and there are several Englishman who play for us. We call them Poms.

Comment: I was aware of the term, I hard just imagined a different origin than what is the case. Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: @Matt Ellen, Nothing at all, a pleasure for me:):)

Comment: I didn't think that alien had this connotation? Is that for sure?

Comment: Perhaps for Brits these are used. The only one I'd see that way here in the USA is `Alien`. The problem is that word has a specific legal definition in immigration law. Either way, it says nothing about the relative wealth of the immigrant in question, so it wouldn't seem to be a good answer to the question posed.

Comment: BBischof: `Alien` is the jargon term that the American government (and therefore many Americans) use for any foreign nationals that are present on U.S. territory.  This would include immigrants who are not citizens as well as temporary visitors, including tourists.

Comment: Have to say the claimed WOP derivation feels mythic. Has a lot in common with the tale of POSH's origin. And the POM for pomegranate makes no sense at all. The English in Australia would never have been considered immigrants. And immigrant plain doesn't rhyme with pomegranate.

Comment: T.E.D. and BBischof, the word *alien* does not have that meaning, in the UK.

Comment: @JoelBrown "alien" is not jargon (and does not depend on where the person is); it is simply a word that means "foreigner" and has had that meaning since before it passed into the English language in the 1300s.  It is used in the immigration and nationality law of probably every English-speaking country, although there is a trend in the last decade or two to prefer other terms.  The main problem with this is that the preferred term is often "noncitizen" or "foreign national," which is usually imprecise on its face and therefore leads to misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tristanr what meaning do you think "alien" has in the UK?  In the context of the Nationality Act, at least, it "means a person who is neither a Commonwealth citizen nor a British protected person nor a citizen of the Republic of Ireland."  If you mean that it isn't slang, and therefore isn't responsive to this question, that is certainly correct.

Answer (score 5):

I have heard the phrase "wretched refuse" used to obliquely refer to poor immigrants. It is a phrase lifted from [the poem on the Statue of Liberty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Colossus), instantly recognizable to any American with a small modicum of education. As such, it actually has a slightly more positive connotation than such a phrase would otherwise have. It probably would only work for immigrants to the USA though.

Generally a term like that is only really needed during an immigration wave. Such waves tend to be centered from one country, so every such term tends to be associated with a particular nationality (usually as an epithet). As such, you will have great trouble finding a word or phrase that doesn't double as a specific racial epithet.

Comment: Anyone with a 'small modicum of education' would simply say 'modicum of education'--most modicums are small.

Answer (score 1):

An American term in wide use over a century ago was "wop," or "without papers."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illegal_immigration

It referred particularly to Italian immigrants, and there are other, less flattering references to them.

Answer (score 0):

FOB stands for "fresh off the boat."  Usually it's used for immigrants with heavy accents or poor English.  It's also derogatory, not humorous and shouldn't be used.

Comment: IMHO it beats the ugly term used for those who instead immigrated overland from the south ("wetbacks" - presuming they swum the Rio Grande).

Comment: In Michigan, FOB and FOP are derogatory terms for people from Ohio.

Comment: FOB sounds like its a made-up phrase--a term Europeans ascribe to Americans who refer to illegal or recent immigrants. I'm American and I have never heard or read this 'FOB' term anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any general BE terms - perhaps asylum seeker if you are the Daily Mail.

Generally it's just the name of the county abbreviated. There are a few offensive terms for inhabitants of certain countries, mick, frog, kraut etc but not specific to immigrants.

There was a case recently where a politician got into trouble for saying 'Jap' for Japanese, he claimed it was the official abbreviation for Japan but it was ruled to be offensive like Paki for pakistani.

Comment: i am also a paki

Comment: @Furqan, and generally paki is regarded as offensive. The question is whether 'jap' is automatically offensive or merely an abbreviation. Obviously it's how it's meant

Comment: Is calling a British person a Brit, or a Swedish person a Swede, or a Finnish person a Finn, offensive?

Comment: @Malvolio - I wouldn't have said so. Calling a Swede a Fin or v.v. probably would be!

Comment: You know why all the trees in Norway lean towards the east? Because Sweden sucks!   Mwa-ha-ha...

Comment: @Malvolio http://www.llund.com/yokes.htm

Comment: In some places of the US, Jap (more specifically JAP or J.A.P.) is short for Jewish-American Princess.

Comment: Furqan, you really should not use the word *Paki* http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/Paki, except in contexts like this, where the word itself is being discussed. It's racially abusive, like the word *nigger* http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/nigger

Answer (score 0):

More of a euphemism than a slang term, but my local public library has a couple of shelves designated as the 'New Americans Center'. (Why it's a 'center' I have no idea.) Of course, many people might resent being called an American before they wanted to be called an American, if that makes sense. On the other hand, I think it's a gesture that wouldn't necessarily get made a lot around here.

As someone has mentioned, FOB is definitely offensive, but I thought I would note that I've not heard it in the Midwest, only in California and almost exclusively to refer to Asians (often by other Asians).

Comment: Using AmE doesn't mean one wants to be called an American. But I am definitely with you on your points.

Comment: I know that a lot of people want to be called "Americans" because it emphasizes that you are part of the country rather than being an outsider. And yes, I've only heard FOB as referring to Asians--at least now.

Comment: if they are already citizens, FOB or BOF or whatever is just nonsense, US isn't a pure country of the red. Your ancestors invaded it. People move down from Canda, up from Mexico, Pru, from Europe, etc and bring all messes there. Then what, should they be called non-immigrants ?\

Comment: @Stack: Whose ancestors are you talking about?

Comment: @Stack Oh, I see what you mean about AmE. It's a section of resources for people new to the country/area (in various languages), rather than books aimed at people learning English.

Answer (score 0):

"Pom" or "Pommy" for a Briton goes at least back to WW2, and quite possibly to WW1.

As I understand it, it derives from "Pomeroy", a snooty British name.

Most often used by the ANZAC troops.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Fuzzy. 
Can you support your answer with references, so that it expresses more than just your opinion?